# object oriented design - should my value objects contain only getters?

Tags: java, oop

In the business logic of my project I mostly have *"value objects"* and *"managers"*

**value objects** are everywhere. They can be User, Car, Photo, Album and so.

**managers** exist to control their value objects. It can be UserManager, CarManager, PhotoManager, AlbumManager and so. They do create/remove/getList and other manipulations with the value objects.

Now I faced with the question: *Should my value objects contain **setters**?*
My first opinion is **no**, because I think its better that value object state **will be controlled only by his manager**.

But there is a bad side - code duplication and apparent double work.

Without setters my manager will have methods like `userManager.addPhoto(userToAddTo, photoToBeAdded)`, that internally calls `user.addPhoto(photo)` (method `addPhoto` exists in the implementation, but not in the interface). Its okay if there are only couple of such methods, but when its getting a lot such "setter" methods, the manager seems to be a lit bit ugly and it is apparent double work.

So, should I use setters in my value objects or not?

Comment: whats wrong with using extentions and factory patterns for storage etc? so you'd have a generic manager class then extend it as required for purpose

Answer (score 0):

Your value objects are part of the data access layer and the managers are part of the business logic. So the setters and getters are definetly part of the data access layer and not of the business logic. You also have to think of the reusability of your entities or of your business logic when you are not sure in which layer you should do an specific action.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture

But be careful. Your entities only should have setters like:

```
    /**
     * @param Name
     */
    public void setName(sName) {
        m_sName = sName;
    }
```

if you would do something specific with some values, its part of the business logic, because of the reusability.

Comment: both value objects and managers are part of the *domain logic*. Access to the data access layer occur via manager implementations, so nobody but them know about data access layer

Comment: the value objects are entities. if you want to store this entities in a database, how cant they be part of the data access layer?

Comment: value objects are just interfaces that used in the domain logic. They can be stored anywhere - filesystem, database and so. Where they are stored - depend on implementation

Comment: Yes u are right. They are objects that provide abstract interfaces to some type of database or other persistence mechanism. So they are definetly part of the data access layer.

Comment: if in the *controller* I call `userManager.get()` (my User got from the database by manager), and then in the same *controller* I call `user.addPhoto(photo)` and `userManager.save(user)` - is User part of data access layer?

Comment: no, not if you do it like this, but i wont do it like in your example. i will gave you and example like i solve this. In the Controller you have only one instance of you userManager. The userManager have an List of users. userr objects only have attributes, setters and getters. In this case the user entity is part of the data access layer, the userManager is part of the businesslogic and the controller is the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "yes," and I'd also avoid things like userManager.addPhoto( userToAddTo, photoToBeAdded ), shifting to a richer domain model like user.addPhoto( photo ).

I think most of the OOD design community has come down on the side of 'go ahead and add setters and getters for properties.' Sure, there are purists who think you should only manage full state at once, but it's just not practical.

If you look at languages like C# or Groovy, they've made the ideas of getters and setters somewhat obsolete, relying on various mechanics to simply deal in directly assignable/readable properties and allowing for some method of 'under-the-hood' addition of get/set logic:

```
class Person {
  String name
  String lastname

  // for some dumb reason, always 'get' upper-cased last names
  String getLastname() {
    return this.lastname.toUpperCase()
  }
}
```

All in all, I'm in favor of OO design where objects represent state business logic, not anemic reflections of simple state like a row in a database table.

I'd also consider asking yourself why you're using simple/dumb value objects to begin with. Is there a need for them, like crossing system boundaries over a wire?

Answer (score 0):

In advance I will say I do not understand the reason you have to split your design between value objects and manager objects, you may as well have a perfectly good reason to do so.  In my case, I always implement data transfer objects with its own getter and setter methods, and if I consider I must defend myself from an API user ;), I try to follow the defensive methods Josh Bloch suggests in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).

This meaning, if I don't want an API user to modify the DTOs I am returning, I will make those objects immutable by using `final` modifiers and if necessary, returning defensive copies of its properties... whatever necessary.  The same way Java does with Strings or Integers.

Of course, if your managers do something else than writing properties, then they are part of the business logic and whatever you are doing is perfectly justified

Comment: the main reason is reusability!

Comment: Is your code an API for someone?  Will someone build code on top of yours?  In that case I would suggest you consider the immutable approach

Comment: Or maybe I am specially dense today to see the reason of the design, so please do not take myself too seriously :P

Answer (score 0):

No, your property has to have a setter to set it at all.  A setter-less property is used when the property is composed of other properties.